# Dropdown box not displaying selected value

Tags: flutter, dart

When I select a value from my dropdown the hint text does not change:

```
    String fontSizeValue;
    new DropdownButton<String>(
              items: new List<double>.generate(72, (i) => i + 2.0).map((double value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value.toString(),
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String _) {
                setState(() {
                  fontSize = double.parse(_);
                  fontSizeValue = _;
                  print(fontSizeValue);
                });
              },
              value: fontSizeValue,
              hint: Text('Select'),
            )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Any idea how I can get the selected value to show instead of "select"? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You did not post enough code, but I'll take a wild guess anyway, because there are a lot of questions with this problem:

Your variable `String fontSizeValue;` is defined locally, probably in the `build` function.

You have to define it in a wider scope, so it will retain it's value after another call to `build` that will happen when you call `setState`. Probably as a class member of your `State` class.